# Android Studio network speed unknown command

Tags: android, android-studio

I am having some trouble with Android studio, as it is giving me Unknown Command when i enter in Network speed command.

I clicked run app, then app starts up in Emulator, in Terminal i typed `telnet localhost 5554`
It asked for Auth and i entered it, and i have a list of help...
but network speed wasnt there....

When i enter in network speed 14.4 80 it responded with

> KO: unknown command, try 'help'

Does anyone know why the network speed command is missing?

Edit: If i use the extended controls, and change the network type inside cellular, then whatever setting i put, the download speed is 0.1mbps, even the setting is HSDPA.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give authorization to get more commands. Your authorization key will be present in `~/.emulator_console_auth_token`. You can authorize using the following command:

`auth <key>`